# TypeError: r.at is not a function error on mobile but not on desktop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I am building a web application using **Next.js** with Turbo Pack.

I have encountered an issue where I am getting a

```
TypeError: r.at is not a function
```

error on my **mobile** device (iPhone) when I access the website using Google Chrome.

I am using **chrome://inspect**

However, I am **not** getting this error when I access the website on my desktop using the Google Chrome developer tools and setting it to an iPhone SE.

I have checked my code and I am not using any function called "at". I have tried clearing my browser cache and cookies on my mobile device, but the error persists.

This error is breaking my website and preventing it from functioning correctly on mobile devices.

I would appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

**Answer:**

I am using Chakra UI. I tried turning off Turbo Pack and deleting my function step by step to find the error. Eventually, I discovered that the error was coming from Chakra UI's Avatar component - something I never would have thought.

Comment: Without your code, it's impossible to tell. Here's my guess anyway: [`Array#at()`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_at) and [`String#at()`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_at) are quite new; only Safari 15.4+ support those two, so if you're using a lower version, try updating Safari. As for why they are called, perhaps they were loaded via a library.

Comment: @InSync Thank you for your comments. I am using Chakra UI. I tried turning off Turbo Pack and deleting my function step by step to find the error. Eventually, I discovered that the error was coming from Chakra UI's Avatar component - something I never would have thought.

Comment: https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/7670

Comment: Please post the answer as a separate answer. Then you can accept your own answer after 48 hours.